# Runtime Error while dynamically adding controls to a userform

Tags: excel, vba, designer, vbe

I'm getting "Object variable or with block variable not set" (Error 91) on the below mentioned line.

```
Set cmd = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "cmdTst")
```

where cmd is defined as

```
Dim cmd As MSForms.CommandButton
```

[image: The watch window for reference (Applied Break on the error line and on Pressing F8)]

Comment: If the code is on the form try `Set cmd = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "cmdTest")`

Comment: It's not giving any runtime error, alright. However, the commandbutton created also vanishes when the code ends.

The whole purpose of using the "Designer" is to make the commandbutton stay even when the code ends.

Comment: Where did you have your code ? it needs to run before the form is loaded.

Comment: As the screenshot suggests, the code is in the Coding Page corresponding to UserForm1, in a Sub ModifyUserForm.

I've tried to put this Sub ModifyUserForm in the Module Coding Page as well. Same error on the same line.

Comment: What event causes the sub to be run ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run your code within the UserForm code module.  However, as @CDP1802 has already mentioned, you'll need to run the code within a regular module.  Then, once your code adds the CommandButton, you'll need to add the UserForm to the UserForms collection, and invoke the Show method, if you want to show your UserForm.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim cmd As MSForms.CommandButton
    
    Set cmd = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "cmdTst")

    VBA.UserForms.Add("UserForm1").Show

End Sub
```